# Deploying to GH pages with Custom Jekyll Plugins

Tags: node.js, ruby, github-actions, jekyll, gitlab-ci.yml

I am trying to deploy a site to gh-pages. I am using this [template](https://github.com/CloudCannon/vonge-jekyll-bookshop-template). The side is a node built site with custom jekyll plugins.

My `.yml` is below.

```
name: Build and Deploy to Github Pages

permissions:
  id-token: write
  pages: write

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Checkout ️
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Setting up Node
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: '16'
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm ci

    - name: Setting up Ruby
      uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
      with: { ruby-version: '3.1.2' }

    - name: Caching Gems
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: vendor/bundle
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-gems-${{ hashFiles('**/Gemfile.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-gems-

    - name: Build Site ️
      run: npm run install-jekyll 
      env:
        NODE_ENV: production

    - name: Upload artifact
      uses: actions/upload-pages-artifact@v1
      with: 
        path: "./site/"

  deploy:
    environment:
      name: github-pages
      url: ${{ steps.deployment.outputs.page_url }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    steps:
      - name: Deploy to GitHub Pages
        id: deployment
        uses: actions/deploy-pages@v1
```

Everything appears to run fine - no errors and GH tells me the site was deployed to zakraicik.github.io fine. However, when I visit the site- it shows 404.

Can anyone help me figure out where my mistake is? I assume it's somewhere in the `.yml` file.

The full repo is available [here](https://github.com/zakraicik/zakraicik.github.io).

Comment: https://github.com/github/pages-gem/issues/171 There are far too many known issues, so remove the plugins first and try again.

Comment: No 404 on your page anymore.